# Two actions when animation ends (setOnFinished)

Tags: java, javafx, css-animations

I've been trying to perform two different actions to the same rectangle after animation is done: the rectangle must change color and the text inside of it must become visible. But the programme only performs the second event, ignoring the first one (even if I switched them). How can I make it work?

```
public void open() {
    RotateTransition trans = new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(1), rec);
    trans.setToAngle(180); 
    trans.setAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
    trans.setOnFinished (event -> tex.setVisible(true));
    trans.setOnFinished (event -> rec.setFill(Color.WHITE));
    trans.play();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

1. Just put them in the same event handler:

   ```
   trans.setOnFinished(event -> {
       text.setVisible(true);
       rec.setFill(Color.WHITE);
   });
   ```
2. or add change listeners to the `statusProperty`:

   ```
   trans.statusProperty().addListener((obs, oldStatus, newStatus) -> {
       if (newStatus == Animation.Status.STOPPED) {
           text.setVisible(true);
       }
   });

   trans.statusProperty().addListener((obs, oldStatus, newStatus) -> {
       if (newStatus == Animation.Status.STOPPED) {
           rec.setFill(Color.WHITE);
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: Thank you!

Is it possible to make one action happen while animation is half way there? Like my rectangle is rotating 180 degrees on Y Axis. I need it to change the color when 90 degrees is done and make text visible when 180 degrees is done.

Comment: Different question, but in short, use a `Timeline` and add event handlers to the relevant key frames.